# Update working branch with remote master

Tags: git

It may have been asked before, but I haven't found the exact answer. This is my graph,

[image]

I'm working on `demo3`. I've made new commits into `demo2` and finally merge them with master. How could I bring those changes into `demo3`? Should I use rebase or merge?

Note: those changes in `demo2` doesn't affect the same lines I'm working on `demo3`.

Comment: Depends, is demo3 pushed to remote and used by others? If not, rebase is fine

Comment: demo3 is only used by me, and I pushed it to remote to see that graph in Github

Comment: If you're asking which one you should use, that's preference on how you want to deal with merging or incorporating the commits. Either one will work

Comment: I have fear of getting my files with that >>>>>> added by git and start searching for them. That shouldn't happen with rebase?

Comment: That can happen with either rebase or merge, it depends on what files were affected between the branches. A "cleaner" history can be done via rebase, and a merge will track what was brought in more visibly

Answer (score 0):

If you have made a commit at branch `demo3`, the `git cherry-pick <commit>` command allows you to take the commit from `demo2` and rebase it in your working branch.
[This explains it in a better way.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#Integrating-Contributed-Work)

Comment: I apreciate your answer but I'd like to use rebase or merge, which I think those are more common commands, and see the differences. I'm confused enough with git to try new commands :S

Comment: I am not sure but I think a `git merge demo2` after a `git checkout demo3` would suffice.